# Transfer models from Stella to NetLogo

Tags: model, netlogo

I’m new in NetLogo and I have a question: is it possible to take a model in Stella and transfer it in NetLogo in some way? I’ll explain:  I'm building an agent-based model for vegetation dynamics in NetLogo,  but to describe the environment (nutrients, water, light etc) I need to use dynamics-models made by Stella (for example: hydrogeological model for the water). Do you think I can do that? If yes, how would I do?

I’m sorry for my english, I’m italian

Thanks,

Regards,
Lorenzo

Comment: There is a system dynamics modeler in netlogo. http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/systemdynamics.html . This is not an answer but perhaps it will help.

Answer (score 1):

I have an answer but it may not be a happy one.

If what you need is to make system dynamics model (SDM) and integrate it with a agent based model. No problem use the built-in System dynamics modeler in netlogo.

http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/systemdynamics.html

If you need to use a specific model made in stella you will have a bit more trouble and will have to rewrite it in the netlogo SDM. Because of the back of an envelope nature of SDMs it should not be too hard. (Make an grad student do it).

I hope this helps.